# Switch to power pump with relay

Tags: switches, relay, timer

I couldn't find this question anywhere else.

I have a pump, a 12v battery and a switch and can purchase any relays etc that may be required.

I want it so that when a switch is triggered and kept on for 3 seconds it starts another circuit, or something, which powers the pump for 10 seconds and then stops, during this 10 seconds the switch may be kept triggered or it may break the circuit but I don't want the pump to stop until the 10 seconds is up.

If the switch is disconnected during the 3 seconds I want the 3 second timer to reset to 0 seconds again.

I hope this explains my problem.

In short:
Switch on for 3 seconds > Pump on for 10 seconds > Reset.

If switch breaks during 3 seconds then reset to 0
If switch breaks during pump for 10 seconds then continue pumping until 10 seconds is reached.

ADDITION:
If the switch is held on thru to 13 seconds then I would like it to retrigger the pump again.

If the switch triggers (held for 3 seconds) whilst the pump is active then I just want it to finish the 10 seconds and wait for another 3 second switch stint, not continue or start another 10 seconds.

Thanks Matt

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably uses a small micro but if you want a non-programmed result then you can charge up a capacitor when a switch is held. The rate that the cap charges is determined by C and a resistor. You can choose RC values that equate to the capacitor attaining a terminal voltage of (say) 6 volts after 3 seconds.

Use a comparator to detect that the capacitor has charged to 6 volts and this event can trigger a 555 timer in monostable mode. The 555 can drive a power transistor that can turn your motor.

What you haven't considered in your question is what happens if the switch is held on for the duration of the ten seconds and thru to 13 seconds - does the motor reactivate?

Also, what is unclear is when the switch retriggers the 3 second timer during the 10 second timer - does the 10 second motor timer reset and extend from that instant.

Use a micro is my advice then you will be able to re-jig things at will.

Comment: Both things I had not thought of. If the switch is held on thru to 13 seconds then I would like it to retrigger the pump again.

If the switch triggers whilst the pump is active then I just want it to finish the 10 seconds and wait for another 3 second switch stint

Comment: With that amount of logic, you really should use a microcontroller. Do you have programming experience? It's not at all difficult if you do. The logic would easily fit in an 8-pin controller.

Comment: What controller do you recommend to use?

Comment: At this level, pretty much any one will do. You only need one input and one output. I did something like this for a client using an Atmel ATTiny13. Upon receiving a switch press it wakes up, checks for a double-click on the switch, then turns on an optically-isolated output for 0.1 second, and goes back to sleep. The entire circuit fits on a PC board that's less than 1" on a side.